# get Data from alamofire (responseString)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift4.1

I am retrieving the data with this code

```
 Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseString() { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                let jsonData = JSON(data)
                print(jsonData)
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print("\(error) - hello world")
            }
    }
```

and the result that has sent by the server is

```
{"result":"Opertion is successfull"}
```

but i just want the value part `"Opertion is successfull"`

Comment: just use `jsonData["result"].string`

Comment: do like `print(jsonData["result"])`

Comment: @Mukesh - inhere ? is not used the swiftyJSON,

Comment: use response.result.value rather than data it will give a dictionary and then you can get a value of result as you fetch any value from dictionary.

Comment: use responseData if you want data

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I think `JSON(data)` is from SwiftyJSON.

Comment: i changed responseString to responseData , then used jsonData["result"] and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code from the almofire [documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#making-a-request)

```
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
    .responseString() { response in
        if let jsonData = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(jsonData)") // serialized json response
        }
}
```